# Customized TreeView: setOnAction for Custom Label in TreeCell

Tags: checkbox, javafx, treeview, listener

I have made a TreeView, represented by a custom cellFactory where each cell is represented by an HBox looking like this.

[image: TreeCell HBox]

How can I access the checkbox so that if you check it, a private boolean field in the corresponding EventTreeItem changes it's value?

**Code:**

```
public class EventTreeItem extends TreeItem<String>{
    SimpleStringProperty item;
    boolean important = true;

    public EventTreeItem(boolean important, int id){
        this.noNode = noNode;
        super.setValue(id);
    }
    public EventTreeItem(){

    }

    public void setImportant(Boolean important){
        this.important = important;
    }
}
```

**CellFactory:**

```
public final class CustomTreeCellFactory extends TreeCell<String>{
private TextField textField;
private HBox hBox;
private HBox hBoxLeaf;

public CustomTreeCellFactory(){
    try {
        hBox = (HBox) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Views/TreCell.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("This didn't work");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        hBoxLeaf = (HBox) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Views/TreCellLowestLevel.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("This didn't work");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    hBoxLeaf.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

}

@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
   super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (item != null) {
        EventTreeItem eventTreeItem = (EventTreeItem) getTreeItem();
        if (getTreeView().getTreeItemLevel(getTreeItem())==1) {
            setGraphic(this.hBox);
            ((CheckBox) ((HBox)getGraphic()).getChildren().get(3)).setSelected(((EventTreeItem) getTreeItem()).important);


           ((Label) hBox.getChildren().get(0)).setText(eventTreeItem.noNode.getEntryNumber() + " " + eventTreeItem.noNode.getClass().getName().split("\\.")[3]);
           ((Label) hBox.getChildren().get(1)).setText(eventTreeItem.noNode.getDate().toString());

        }else if (getTreeView().getTreeItemLevel(getTreeItem())==2){
            setGraphic(this.hBoxLeaf);
        }
    } else {
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

}

**NodeTreeView**

```
public class NodeTreeView implements ChartView{
private FilteredListModel filteredListModel;
TreeItem<String> root;
AnchorPane parent;
TreeView treeView;

public NodeTreeView(FilteredListModel filteredListModel, TabPane tabPane) throws IOException {
    this.filteredListModel = filteredListModel;
    parent = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Views/TryTreeViewInAnchorPane.fxml"));
    parent.setVisible(true);
    generateTree();

    }


private void generateTree() {
        this.root = new EventTreeItem();
        root.setExpanded(true);
        filteredListModel.makeEventNodeArrays().forEach(node->{
            EventTreeItem item = new EventTreeItem((EventNoNode) node);
            EventTreeItem item2 = new EventTreeItem();
            root.getChildren().add(item);
            item.getChildren().add(item2);
        });



    treeView = (TreeView) parent.getChildren().get(0);
    treeView.setRoot(root);
    treeView.setShowRoot(false);
    treeView.setEditable(true);
    treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> param) {
            return new CustomTreeCellFactory();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener to checkbox's `selectedProperty` in your `CustomTreeCellFactory` constructor (which is not a factory, btw; you should call it `CustomTreeCell` instead):

```
public CustomTreeCellFactory() {
    // ...
    CheckBox checkbox = ...;
    checkbox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
        ((EventTreeItem) getTreeItem()).important = isSelected;
    });
}
```

Btw, it is probably a better idea to make the "important" flag be part of the item, i.e. instead of `TreeView<String>`, you would have `TreeView<MyItem>` where `MyItem` is

```
class MyItem {
    String item;
    boolean important;

    MyItem(String item, boolean important) {
        this.item = item;
        this.important = important;
    }
}
```

Comment: You made my day. The naming to factory has really confused me. I don't know why I did that. All the HBox items can simply be declared in the constructor, along with the listeners. I'll never forgive myself.

Comment: I'm kind of new to StackOverflow, but should I edit my OP to clean it up? And should I answer my question with what I ended up with?